# Sampling a stereo WAV file in JAVA - get amplitudes

Tags: java, audio, wav, sampling

Say, I have got a wav file (a stereo song) and I want to get 2 arrays of double - left and right channels. I looked up for a while, although I was able to find a way of getting amplitude array of values between -1 and 1 for mono files, I was not able to do it for stereo. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `AudioInputStream` to read the file or something else?

Comment: Yeap, I'm using `AudioInputStream`.

Comment: show how you did it for mono - otherwise giving away packaged answers that you dont even understand is no use